# How to update all posts at once?

Tags: posts, date

Like "after host change, we update our permalink"

[image]

Comment: i try to finding ans from stackexchange but no ans work for me.

Comment: No one !! :( :(

Comment: ...it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe try a fuller description?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to mass change old URLs in website database after migration. You can do it either by using plugin or manually.

**Plugin Method:**

The [Velvet Blues Update URLs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) plugin enables you to change the URLs at various places, like posts and pages excerpts. Follow these steps:

1. Install and activate Velvet Blues Update URLs plugin.
2. Head to **Tools > Update URLs**.
3. Insert the old site address in the **Old URL** field.
4. Insert the new site address in the **New URL** field.
5. Check the boxes in front of **URLs in page content**, **URLs in
   excerpts**, **URLs in links**, **URLs for attachments**, and **URLs
   in custom fields and meta boxes**.
6. Finally, click on **Update URLs NOW** button.

**Manual Method:**

There are various ways of mass changing old URLs manually. They are:

1. Changing the URL directly in the database
2. Use PHPMyAdmin script for Search and Replace in Database

You will find the details of the manual methods [right here](https://blog.templatetoaster.com/update-old-urls-in-database/).